# How to use robocopy with exclusions

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, robocopy

I am using robocopy to copy folders and files from source to destination.

origin_path:

```
folder1
folder2
folder3
file1.txt
file2.log
file3.png
```

dest_path:

```
folder_important
folder1
folder2
```

this is my command

```
set exclude_ext_from_copy=*.log *.txt*
set exclude_folder_from_copy=folder3

robocopy "origin_path" "dest_path" /E /COPYALL /PURGE /MIR /IS /IT /TEE /FFT /ETA /R:10 /W:5 /ZB /V /XF %exclude_ext_from_copy% /XD %exclude_folder_from_copy% /LOG:"%HOMEPATH%\Desktop\log.txt"
```

out on dest_path:

```
folder1
folder2
file3.png
```

You can see that it excluded from the copy "folder3" and files with extensions "* .log" and "* .txt". So far so good.

Now i want to prevent robocopy deleting folder "folder_important" on 'dest_path'. How can I exclude it (or protect it from deletion). Thk

failed attempts:

```
attrib +s +h dest_path\folder_important
robocopy etc etc
attrib -s -h dest_path\folder_important
```

Comment: you already seem to be aware of the `/XD` Exclude directory switch, so why are you not using it to achieve the result your question seeks?

Comment: how would i use it in this case? (/XD %exclude_folder_from_copy% /dest_path/folder_important)

Comment: An idea for learning / problem solving: create a couple of meaningles folders with dud files, and test the command structure on them.

Comment: @T3RR0R You are right. Problem solved. Can add to / XD the extra folder which I don't want to be removed from target. If you wish, you can post your answer to select it as correct. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple example of testing you are using the correct command structure prior to applying it to important file

test program:

```
CD %~dp0
Tree /F /A
Robocopy source dest /Purge /Mir /XD leave retain
Tree /F /A
Exit /B
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\tcdou\Desktop\rcT>CD C:\Users\tcdou\Desktop\rcT\ 

C:\Users\tcdou\Desktop\rcT>Tree /F /A 
Folder PATH listing for volume Windows
Volume serial number is E05B-0DE4
C:.
|   demo.log
|   RCexample.bat
|   
+---dest
|   |   one.txt
|   |   
|   +---Remove
|   \---retain
\---source
    |   one.txt
    |   
    \---leave

C:\Users\tcdou\Desktop\rcT>Robocopy source dest /Purge /Mir /XD leave retain 

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows                              
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : Saturday, 16 May 2020 10:17:02 PM
   Source : C:\Users\tcdou\Desktop\rcT\source\
     Dest : C:\Users\tcdou\Desktop\rcT\dest\

    Files : *.*

 Exc Dirs : leave
        retain

  Options : *.* /S /E /DCOPY:DA /COPY:DAT /PURGE /MIR /R:1000000 /W:30 

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                       1    C:\Users\tcdou\Desktop\rcT\source\
    *EXTRA Dir        -1    C:\Users\tcdou\Desktop\rcT\dest\Remove\

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

               Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
    Dirs :         2         0         2         0         0         2
   Files :         1         0         1         0         0         0
   Bytes :         0         0         0         0         0         0
   Times :   0:00:00   0:00:00                       0:00:00   0:00:00
   Ended : Saturday, 16 May 2020 10:17:02 PM


C:\Users\tcdou\Desktop\rcT>Tree /F /A 
Folder PATH listing for volume Windows
Volume serial number is E05B-0DE4
C:.
|   demo.log
|   RCexample.bat
|   
+---dest
|   |   one.txt
|   |   
|   \---retain
\---source
    |   one.txt
    |   
    \---leave

C:\Users\tcdou\Desktop\rcT>Exit /B
```

The obvious learning from this simple test is that you can use the /XD switch to specify multiple folders to exclude from the operation in both the source and destination folder.

Comment: One question: is /xd "folder_a" "folder_b" or /xd "folder_a" /xd "folder_b" ?

Comment: The example I provided in the answer for usage should be clear on the matter - The switch is used only once, with folders to be excluded listed after the switch.